# Benchmarks for threads java

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm looking for benchmarks which compare the differences between multiple threads accessing a synchronized map compared to threads which do not, how much speed is lost when threads share maps, versus just copying and operating on them separately?

Comment: Sharing maps versus copying and operating on maps separately (or using immutable maps that don't need to be copied) are quite different approaches to a problem, so I'd be surprised if anyone has written a benchmark that gives a clean comparison.

Comment: Speed loss depends on the usage pattern. It is easier to write a benchmark that suits your particular needs than to find one.

Comment: I agree with Adam Mihalcin and dasblinkenlight, probably easiest to whip one up yourself.  I'd be surprised if copying maps frequently was more optimal than just letting the Map locks do their thing.  Also its probably a more complex solution, and unless you really really need the speed, prob not worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this test comparing [Synchronized vs Lock performance](http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/synchronized-vs-lock-performance.html)

I would use the ConcurrentHashMap or ConcurrentSkipListMap if you are concerned about performance of multiple threads accessing the same Map.